# PHP + cURL website login '403 Forbidden'

Tags: php, curl, cookies, https, http-status-code-403

I've been working through many tutorials and questions on here but still can't work out why I am getting '403 Forbidden' when trying to log into a website using cURL and PHP. The website login in question is: https://science.swansea.ac.uk/intranet/accounts/login/ .

The initial request works (code 200) and the cookie is saved to file. I then strip this cookie and add it to the post form as required.

Also I must add that I am running this php script on a localhost wamp server if that could be an issue?

If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great as I've been working on this for a while now with no result.

PHP + cURL code:

```
<?php

    $base_url  = 'https://science.swansea.ac.uk/intranet/accounts/login/?next=/intranet/';
    $login_url  = 'https://science.swansea.ac.uk/intranet/accounts/login/';
    $user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36";
    $username = '*******';
    $password = '*******';
    $cookie = 'cookie.txt';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $base_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$user_agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate, br');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath($cookie));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, realpath($cookie));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, fopen(realpath("verbose.txt"), 'w'));

    $resp = curl_exec($ch);
    var_dump($resp);


    $headers = array(
        'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Connection: keep-alive',
        'Cache-Control: max-age=0',
        'Origin: https://science.swansea.ac.uk',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1',
        'Referer: https://science.swansea.ac.uk/intranet/accounts/login/?next=/intranet/',
        'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8'
    );


    // Strip cookie to get token
    $csrfmiddlewaretoken = explode('csrftoken', file_get_contents(realpath($cookie)));
    $csrfmiddlewaretoken = trim($csrfmiddlewaretoken[1]);
    $csrfmiddlewaretoken = substr($csrfmiddlewaretoken, 0, strpos($csrfmiddlewaretoken, "#"));

    $post = array(
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken' => $csrfmiddlewaretoken,
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password,
        'next' => "/intranet/"
    );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $login_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));

    // Add headers
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);


      //Set headers out for debug
     // curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

    $exec = curl_exec($ch);
    echo($exec);

    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $hinfo = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);

    if ($info['http_code'] != 200) {
        echo "Login failed! HTTP code {$info['http_code']}<br>\n";
        var_dump($exec);

        // Echo post params
        $params= http_build_query($post);
        $params = str_replace("%0D%0A", '', $params);
        echo("$params <br>\n");
        echo($hinfo);
        exit;
    }

    echo "Login successful!<br>\n";

    // you are now logged in, use $ch to request pages as the logged in user

    $url = $base_url;

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);

    $account = curl_exec($ch);

?>
```

Verbose Output:

```
*   Trying 137.44.2.221...
* Connected to science.swansea.ac.uk (137.44.2.221) port 443 (#0)
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* NPN, negotiated HTTP1.1
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=GB; ST=West Glamorgan; L=SWANSEA; O=Swansea University; OU=College of Science; CN=science.swansea.ac.uk
*  start date: Apr 29 11:54:39 2016 GMT
*  expire date: Apr 29 11:54:36 2019 GMT
*  issuer: C=BM; O=QuoVadis Limited; CN=QuoVadis Global SSL ICA G2
*  SSL certificate verify result: self signed certificate in certificate chain (19), continuing anyway.
> GET /intranet/accounts/login/?next=/intranet/ HTTP/1.1
Host: science.swansea.ac.uk
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Cookie: csrftoken=BNmrRv29juCijlFX63mpMkzkL4pO2x67; sessionid=unanto4vhu3k4s3cz3ngyjfq5zloihjr

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Thu, 19 Jan 2017 21:24:10 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Server: gunicorn/0.17.2
< Last-Modified: Thu, 19 Jan 2017 21:24:10 GMT
< Expires: Thu, 19 Jan 2017 21:24:10 GMT
< Vary: Cookie
< Cache-Control: max-age=0
* Replaced cookie csrftoken="BNmrRv29juCijlFX63mpMkzkL4pO2x67" for domain science.swansea.ac.uk, path /intranet/, expire 1516310650
< Set-Cookie: csrftoken=BNmrRv29juCijlFX63mpMkzkL4pO2x67; expires=Thu, 18-Jan-2018 21:24:10 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/intranet/; secure
* Replaced cookie sessionid="unanto4vhu3k4s3cz3ngyjfq5zloihjr" for domain science.swansea.ac.uk, path /intranet/, expire 1485033850
< Set-Cookie: sessionid=unanto4vhu3k4s3cz3ngyjfq5zloihjr; expires=Sat, 21-Jan-2017 21:24:10 GMT; httponly; Max-Age=172800; Path=/intranet/; secure
< Content-Encoding: gzip
< 
* Connection #0 to host science.swansea.ac.uk left intact
* Found bundle for host science.swansea.ac.uk: 0x264f6c800d0 [can pipeline]
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host science.swansea.ac.uk
* Connected to science.swansea.ac.uk (137.44.2.221) port 443 (#0)
> POST /intranet/accounts/login/ HTTP/1.1
Host: science.swansea.ac.uk
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Cookie: csrftoken=BNmrRv29juCijlFX63mpMkzkL4pO2x67; sessionid=unanto4vhu3k4s3cz3ngyjfq5zloihjr
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: https://science.swansea.ac.uk
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Referer: https://science.swansea.ac.uk/intranet/accounts/login/
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Content-Length: 140
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

* upload completely sent off: 140 out of 140 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 403 FORBIDDEN
< Date: Thu, 19 Jan 2017 21:24:10 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Server: gunicorn/0.17.2
< Vary: Cookie
* Replaced cookie sessionid="unanto4vhu3k4s3cz3ngyjfq5zloihjr" for domain science.swansea.ac.uk, path /intranet/, expire 1485033850
< Set-Cookie: sessionid=unanto4vhu3k4s3cz3ngyjfq5zloihjr; expires=Sat, 21-Jan-2017 21:24:10 GMT; httponly; Max-Age=172800; Path=/intranet/; secure
< Content-Encoding: gzip
< 
* Connection #0 to host science.swansea.ac.uk left intact
```

Comment: i have never seen a curl build with br (Brotli) encoding support. are you sure your curl is compiled with br? if not, you'll run in to trouble the first time the server actually decides to use br encoding..

Comment: sorry for the late reply @hanshenrik . This Brotli coding I had simply added when banging my head against the wall trying to get this to work. Thanks for the tip though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is at these lines:

```
$csrfmiddlewaretoken = explode('csrftoken', file_get_contents(realpath($cookie)));
$csrfmiddlewaretoken = trim($csrfmiddlewaretoken[1]);
$csrfmiddlewaretoken = substr($csrfmiddlewaretoken, 0, strpos($csrfmiddlewaretoken, "#"));
```

if you put an `echo ']'.$csrfmiddlewaretoken.'[';` after this line `$csrfmiddlewaretoken = substr($csrfmiddlewaretoken, 0, strpos($csrfmiddlewaretoken, "#"));`
 you can see that there is an **<del>extra space</del>(see update)** at the end of the `$csrfmiddlewaretoken` string. So this will be a different token from what server is looking for and the reason for getting the `< HTTP/1.1 403 FORBIDDEN` response.

So just change the last two lines to the above block to this:

```
$csrfmiddlewaretoken = $csrfmiddlewaretoken[1];
$csrfmiddlewaretoken = trim(substr($csrfmiddlewaretoken, 0, strpos($csrfmiddlewaretoken, "#")));
```

And you will get a `< HTTP/1.1 200 OK` response

**Update**

That extra space, was actually `%0D%0A`This is ASCII character "13" and "10" which is equal too CR(Carriage Return or \r) + LF(Line Feed or \n) or to put it in simple words, an **Enter**

If you look into the `cookie.txt` file, you have

```
science.swansea.ac.uk   FALSE   /intranet/  TRUE    1516357443  csrftoken   s5mbN2Fa5tty4UAkjjSix4cxlBLygsHg
#HttpOnly_science.swansea.ac.uk FALSE   /intranet/  TRUE    1485080643  sessionid   xvy7rikn6d3iv5xq0g6yisdrv00yjj0z
```

Which means you have `csrftoken + token` in one line and the next `#` in the beginning of the another line. And because of this line:

```
$csrfmiddlewaretoken = substr($csrfmiddlewaretoken, 0, strpos($csrfmiddlewaretoken, "#"))
```

You are deleting anything after `#` of the last line but you are kipping the \r\n(enter) before it. You had to remove it from the end of your string

Comment: Thank you so much! This is something I've been stumped over for a long time. echo($params) was printing "csrfmiddlewaretoken=BNmrRv29juCijlFX63mpMkzkL4pO2x67&username=" leading me to believe my token was fine (cannot see whitespace). Is there a reason for this? Just so I know for future reference.

Comment: @TheEnglishMan_ :) You are welcome, just added some update to my answer and explained more about the origin of your problem...

Comment: I can see that you have this line in your code: `$params = str_replace("%0D%0A", '', $params);` and you have tried to remove these "%0D%0A" from the string, BUT, you are doing it after this line `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));` So technically, what you are sending to the `science.swansea.ac.uk` server have these two characters in it. If you just had done it before that line, you wouldn't face that problem

Comment: That makes perfect sense now. Thanks again! :)